# How to connect to Azure Managed MySQL Database from Azure Functions in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, azure, azure-functions

### Issue

Our Python app on Azure Functions cannot connect to our Azure Managed MySQL database. The function runs fine when testing locally using `func start`. We have no issues connecting to the database or performing cursor operations. However, when deployed on Azure we get the error below.

We have tried using different SSL certs and turning off SSL entirely from the database. Nothing has worked so far.

#### Error

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '<server_host>', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 436, in switch_to_ssl
    self.sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/<script_folder>/__init__.py", line 88, in main
    host=os.environ['MYSQL_HOST'],
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 177, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 781, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 288, in _open_connection
    self._ssl, self._conn_attrs)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 197, in _do_auth
    ssl_options.get('version', None))
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 444, in switch_to_ssl
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '<server_host>', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)
```

#### Conncetion Code

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user=os.environ['MYSQL_USER'],
    password=os.environ['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
    database=os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
    host=os.environ['MYSQL_HOST'],
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

#### Requirements

```
astroid==2.3.3
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-core==1.1.1
azure-functions==1.0.7
azure-identity==1.1.0
azure-keyvault==4.0.0
azure-keyvault-certificates==4.0.0b7
azure-keyvault-keys==4.0.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.0.0
azure-storage-blob==12.1.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.3.0
isodate==0.6.0
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==8.0.2
msal==1.0.0
msal-extensions==0.1.3
msrest==0.6.10
mysql-connector-python==8.0.18
numpy==1.17.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==0.25.3
portalocker==1.5.2
protobuf==3.11.1
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.4.4
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.13.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.7
wrapt==1.11.2
zipp==0.6.0
```

Comment: check the OpenSSL version https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87121

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Neither of their workarounds worked. For `Use the C Extension (use_pure = False)`, errored with: MySQL Connector/Python C Extension not available. And for `Change the define symbol to ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
  From Connector/Python 2.1.7 on Oracle Linux 7:`, we do not have the necessary access on the managed database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the SSL CA File. Download the certificate from:

https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem

Include the file in your build. Modify the example code below to specify the path.

Notice the following screenshot. In your code specify the full path to the Certificate Authority:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user=os.environ['MYSQL_USER'],
    password=os.environ['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
    database=os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
    host=os.environ['MYSQL_HOST'],
    ssl_ca='/home/site/wwwroot/ssl/BalitimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: This was the same the solution from the Microsoft help desk, but we are still getting the same error. For now we have set `ssl_disabled=True` on all connections to prevent the connector from trying the ssl handshake. This seems to work, but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed - Pymysql

Unfortunately Microsoft help desk was not able to resolve the issue with the **mysql.connector**. We found that the **pymysql** package was able to securely connect using the SSL CA file. Below is our final code for our database connections.

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import pathlib

def get_ssl_cert():     
    current_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent    
    return str(current_path / 'BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem')

### SQL Process
# Connection
conn = pymysql.connect(
    user=os.environ['MYSQL_USER'],
    password=os.environ['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
    db=os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
    host=os.environ['MYSQL_HOST'],
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
    ssl={'ssl': {'ssl-ca': get_ssl_cert()}}
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Being able to facilitate SSL CA - is that a new feature?

Comment: Not a new feature. It is just poorly documented on Azure Functions with python.